How to approximate $\frac{(2n+1)}{2^n} \int_0^1 \left( 1-x^2+\sqrt{1+2x^2-3x^4}\right)^ndx$
Let
$$
f(x) = \frac{1-x^2+\sqrt{1+2x^2-3x^4}}{2}
$$
How to approximate the integral
$$
I_n = (2n+1)\int_0^1 f(x)^n dx?
$$
Experiments seem to indicate that it is something like $cn^{0.75}+1$ where $c$ is somewhere around $1.8128$.
Context
This formula appears in the expected value of crosses placed on a $2 \times n$ board before a square block of $4$ appears (i.e there are crosses on four squares that share a corner) when placing them randomly. Using transfer matrix we get that the generating function for boards without square blocks enumerated by number of crosses is
$$\left(
\begin{array}{r}1 & 1 & 1
\end{array} \right)
\left(\begin{array}{rrr}
1 & 1 & 1 \\
2 x & 2 x & 2 x \\
x^{2} & x^{2} & 0
\end{array}\right)^{n-1}
\left(
\begin{array}{rrr}
1 \\
2x \\
x^2
\end{array} \right)
$$
Then using the fact that $(2n+1)\int_0^1 x^k(1-x)^{2n-k}dx = {2n \choose k}^{-1}$ and diagonalizing the matrix we get that the expected value is
$$
(2n+1) \int_{0}^{1}b\left(x\right)^{n-1}\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1+x^{2}-2x^{4}}{2\sqrt{1+2x^2-3x^4}}\right)-a\left(x\right)^{n-1}\left(\frac{1+x^{2}-2x^{4}}{2\sqrt{1+2x^2-3x^4}}-\frac{1}{2}\right)dx
$$
where $b(x)=f(x)$ and $a(x) = \frac{1-x^2-\sqrt{1+2x^2-3x^4}}{2}$. The $a$-part tends to zero and the coefficient of $b$ is approximately $1$ where $b^{n-1}$ isn't small, so therefore I'm only asking about the $b$. See this Desmos for experiments.

UPDATE My try:
Leaving out and changing irrelevant parts, let's try to calculate $\lim_{n\to \infty} n^{1 \over 4}\int_0^1 \left(\frac{1-x^2+\sqrt{1+2x^2-3x^4}}{2}\right)^ndx$. Changing variable $t=n^{1 \over 4}x$, we have
$$
\int_0^{n^{1 \over 4}} \left(\frac{\sqrt{n}-t^2+\sqrt{n+2\sqrt{n}t^2-3t^4}}{2\sqrt{n}}\right)^n dt
$$
Now the integrand seems to converge as $n \to \infty$, so this seems promising...

Since $-\ln f(x) \sim x^4$ as $x\to 0$ and $f(x)$ has its absolute maximum of $1$ there, Laplace's method gives
$$\int_0^1f(x)^n \mathrm{d} x\sim\tfrac{\Gamma(\tfrac{1}{4})}{4} n^{-1/4}\approx\tfrac{1.8128}{2}n^{-1/4}\text{,}$$
consistent with your experiment. You can derive further terms in the expansion to get a better asymptotic approximation.
